# I can't simulate this circuit in LTspice

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, ltspice, npn

I can't simulate the circuit in this picture. When I try to run it gives an error for missing I value. Could you help me? Could you tell me what Vce and Vbe are?

[image]

Comment: The Param must be in braces (curly braces). But without seeing your actual LT spice circuit I can't answer your question. Vce and Vbe should have been explained in your lessons before this.

Comment: I find it hard to believe your teacher simply handed this assignment to you without telling you more, or even having shown you a bit of basics about SPICE simulations. Especially since I see SPICE commands and references for `BC327.txt` in the problem text.

Comment: Show a screen shot of your LTspice schematic.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I'm not surprised. I've attended these classes, recently, at the community college level. The teachers were simply incompetent, the classes held online and not in person because of COVID, and there were only two part time tutors available and it was hard to get help. Meanwhile, the class was moving very fast forward. I can't speak for the OP, of course. But I'm not at all surprised when students are left with inadequate supports or information. It quite literally tore me apart to get to know students trying very hard, loaded down with classwork in an inadequate situation.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen In fact, if you look at this situation and the schematic, the **RB** resistor is completely irrelevant. There's no possible good reason for including it, let alone assigning it a 100k value. (Perhaps measuring the current source voltage helps to know what voltage source might be needed?) So while it's possible that its value will come later in the curriculum (about which I don't know), given what I see in isolation it might lead to either incorrect assumptions or false ideas that will come back later to haunt some students.

Comment: @jonk That's really bad news, but I have to be neutral and say that, at least in my experience, students, in general, are mostly yawning than learning; but teachers should do their jobs. I admit I haven't looked closely at the schematic, and was more distracted by the red requirements (you're right about `Rb`). Still, even for that case, I'd say a better way to go would be a tutorial for the tool you're about to spend time with, learning. OP's question makes me think the current source was simply placed, and nothing else. But, if true, the real pity is the half-baked knowledge (taught).

Comment: @Arsenal thanks it worked. But lecturer didn't explain Vce and Vbe in assignment and i don't know if he explained it in lessons or not because i can't follow the lessons.

Comment: @jonk yes you are right. Lecturer didn't even tell us what LT Spice is . Students try to learn themselves by youtube or other sources.

Comment: @Mert When I get a moment, I'll try and write something up.

Comment: @Mert Thanks for the opportunity to write. Hopefully, some of what I added may help a little.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I've noticed that Mert is actively working to learn. See [this recent question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/601715/38098), for example. I'm seeing good faith here. I think that bodes well and helps justify some of my own faith.

Comment: @jonk Answers of people in there helps me to improve. Especially your answers and interest. Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Spice Preface

There are, today, more than a few free Spice programs available. LTspice is one of them and one I use, regularly. When I started using LTspice many years ago, it was the ***only*** free Spice program that included a good schematic capture component. Today, that's no longer true and there are more choices. But LTspice is a good option for some.

Most Spice programs share a core component developed at UC Berkeley in California which has evolved over the years. This core component was designed back in the day when we didn't have graphics displays (other than ridiculously expensive research units.) And at the time, we had card punches and card readers. So Spice was designed to read one card at a time, parse it, and process the information into internal tables that represented the schematic, internally. There was no graphical input at the time. There would also be cards that described what was desired as output, too. Even to this very day, programs like LTspice turn your graphical schematic into these ancient cards for processing, using the UC Berkeley code or some modern modification of it. LTspice provides a menu option where you can see these cards, in fact!

### Terms

First off, you asked about \$V_{_\text{CE}}\$ and \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$. These just mean the voltage between two points on the transistor. Here, this means the voltage between the collector and the emitter (\$V_{_\text{CE}}\$) or the voltage between the base and the emitter (\$V_{_\text{CE}}\$.) **C** means collector, **E** means emitter, and **B** means base. So that's why the terminology there.

Datasheets will use a lot of these kinds of variables/symbols and I recommend that if you want to compile a list of terms to try and understand, then grab up some datasheets and just write what you see down on paper and then search for them on the web. Over time, you'll get a feel for more and more. There will always be some that you don't know. But as you pick up more of these, that fact alone will help you work out the others you don't know, more easily. So just think of this as a work in progress, a process you have to slowly go through.

### Your Task

Using LTspice, you have two options for capturing the schematic. You can either just write down the cards themselves or else you can use the schematic capture process.

You have specific instructions about a particular BJT. This is represented in the work statement when it writes:

```
.include BC237.txt
```

You should load that file up with a text editor and read it. Better yet, post it in your question here. It should be a line that includes something like:

```
.model BC237 NPN(IS=1E-14 VAF=100 BF=200 IKF=0.3 ....... )
```

That's just a bunch of coded numbers that helps LTspice model the BJT. Someone else created that for you and you are supposed to tell LTspice about it, using that .include card.

I don't have the time to walk you through the schematic capture part of it. But the result might look something like this:

[image]

You will have to edit each component. And that means you have to learn how to use LTspice. There's nothing I can reasonably do to document all that here. You will have to just learn as you go, I think.

Let's take a look at the cards that the above schematic produces:

```
V1 Vcc 0 0
RC Vcc Vc 1k
RB Vb VI1 100k
Q1 Vc Vb 0 0 BC237
I1 0 VI1 {I}
.include BC237.txt
.step param I 10uA 50uA 10uA
.dc V1 0V 10V 0.005V
```

The first letter of each card tells LTspice what kind of device is being indicated. So **V** for a voltage source, **R** for a resistor, **Q** for a BJT, etc. This is followed by a unique identifier. So the **C** added to **R** means the resistor is named **C**. The **B** following the other one names that resistor **B**, of course. And so on.

Once the unique identifier is done then a node name is added, one for each available node. So resistors have only two nodes, but a BJT has three. You can name these, too, to anything you want -- except 0. That is reserved for "ground."

A card with a dot (.) in front is a command and not an electronic part.

If you carefully look over the above, you should be able to work out how it relates to your schematic. It may be worth some time to do that, too. Up to you.

Note that I used {I} in the schematic for the current source. This is needed because the {} tells LTspice that there is an expression to be evaluated and not just a simple number. That causes LTspice to go look for the variable **I**. (It turns out that the .STEP card will generate successive values for it.)

The .DC card causes a DC sweep using those values shown in your problem statement.

Once you do all of this, you can right-click and run things. At that point a blank chart will show up. You can then click on nodes in the schematic to get the curves you want. Or you can click-and-drag in order to get a voltage difference curve. If you are careful about moving the mouse, you can even get currents into or out of a pin. But this is getting beyond the scope of what I wanted to write out.

### P.S.

> Later, perhaps in a day or so, I want to write something for
> @aconcernedcitizen to describe recent experiences I had that relate
> directly to the OP's situation, it appears. When I get a moment for
> that, I'll add it here. It will be entirely superfluous to the
> question, though. And I may delete it in another few days, as it
> really doesn't belong here.

**The promised section was provided for more than a day, but is now removed.**

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I'll leave this up for two days and then edit it back out. (Unless instructed in no uncertain terms by mods to do it earlier.)

Comment: @jonk Sir, I just read it and I want to thank you for your time and interest. I agree with you about your complaint. I hope this site and maybe the world will be much better in the future thanks to you and people like you.

Comment: Also my quesiton was closed. I don't understand exactly. But I hope you can help me for the next questions that I will ask.

Comment: @Mert I'll try. If I'm not reaching you, the fact that you are trying means I'll try, as well. So feel free to ask for better explanations or more complete ones. If I can improve something I'm writing so that it reaches you, chances are it will also reach others better, as well. And that's a good thing.