# Why does this LTspice schematic simulation have five pen plots?

Tags: voltage, current, ltspice, simulation, npn

I ran the schematic at the first picture but it gave five graphs like in the second picture. Is there a mistake?

[image]

[image]

Comment: No is not a mistake. What you see is an output characteristic Ic vs Vce for a given base current.

Comment: The .step command does that for you. In the plot settings, you can pick out just one if you want.

Answer (score 10):

You set the value of I to vary from 10u to 50u in steps of of 10u. That gives five total values and thus five total plots.

Comment: @Mert You have serveral options with step, a fixed list or a range with stepping as you have provided.

Answer (score 8):

There's really no need at all for the base resistor. I think I mentioned this to you, earlier. All it does is modify the voltage across the current source. It changes nothing else with respect to the BJT, the analysis, or the simulation results.

So, the following is adequate:

[image]

I've left the colors just as you have them, except that my lines are 5 pixels (instead of 1) in thickness. I used the Waveforms tab of the control panel to change that width (it shows 2 there, but I selected 5 for the purposes of making them thick enough for displaying better at EESE):

[image]

If you now go to the Drafting Options tab of the control panel and select the Color Scheme (button):

[image]

You can then select the WaveForm tab and see all your colors listed in order:

[image]

You can see the color order by just observing how the colors are shown at the top (V[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SRA4.png), V[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x907m.png), etc.) That's the order that LTspice uses in showing your traces. Since you have five base currents to step through, LTspice will start the first trace with the color shown for V[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SRA4.png) when running through your first base current, which is \$10\:\mu\text{A}\$. It will then select the next color for the next stepped value of base current. And so on.

There's nothing wrong with your screen! That's the way LTspice shows you the results you wanted.

Comment: I don't see how adjusting line width and colors or removing a resistor answers the question.

Comment: @asdfex It doesn't. It explains how I prepared the answer. But other parts do. One doesn't have to be 100% parsimonious. Are you offended by the addition?